# How to ignore interrupts with piped commands

Tags: bash, pipe, interrupt

In the following chain of piped commands, when an interrupt is sent with Ctrl-C, `ping` is able to print its summary statistics before exiting, as long as `tee` has the `-i` (ignore interrupts) flag:

`ping -D localhost 2>&1 | tee -a -i ping.log`

However, with another command in the chain, `ping`'s summary does not get printed:

`` ping -D localhost 2>&1 | sed -u 's/^\[\([0-9]*\.[0-9]*\)\]\(.*$\)/echo "[`date -d @\1 +"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"`] \2"/e' | tee -a -i ping.log ``

How can the above be made to print the summary?

Does `sed` have an option to ignore interrupts? In general how can interrupts be handled gracefully with piped commands?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`` ping -D localhost 2>&1 | (trap '' INT; exec sed -u 's/^\[\([0-9]*\.[0-9]*\)\]\(.*$\)/echo "[`date -d @\1 +"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"`] \2"/e') | tee -a -i ping.log ``

Calling `trap '' INT` tells the shell to ignore SIGINT. The `exec` is optional but nice to have, since the subshell process is no longer necessary after the trap.

Comment: Thanks that works. Is this approach of using a `trap` statement in a pipe considered good practice? Which signals can/should be intercepted in this way?

Comment: I can't think of anything wrong with using `trap` like this. You can't intercept SIGKILL or SIGSTOP this way (or any other way). You shouldn't intercept SIGFPE, SIGILL, or SIGSEGV, as this can cause undefined behavior. You can try to intercept SIGCHLD, but this may get reset depending on what flavor of Unix/Linux you're on. Anything else is fine, as long as the program you're executing doesn't care about it.